# Synchronous rendering of v-for SFC components in VueJS 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have created 2 files for demonstration of my issue.

Parent.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import TypeWriter from "./TypeWriter.vue";

const strings = ref([
    "first_string",
    "second_string",
    "third_string"
]);
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="string in strings">
            <TypeWriter :string="string" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and

TypeWriter.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    string: String
});

const messageWrapper = ref(null);

function printMessage() {
    const target = messageWrapper.value;
    const message = props.string;
    
    // Code to print message gradually in div.typewriter-message element
}

onMounted(() => {
    printMessage(messageWrapper.value);
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="typewriter-message" ref="messageWrapper"></div>
</template>
```

As you can see visual rendering of TypeWriter component takes time and is not displayed instantly. However all components are populated instantly in v-for so all three elements will start to render at the same time.

I would like to achieve rendering of each TypeWriter component one by one. So the next one will start to render only after the previous one is fully rendered. Any ideas how to achieve that?

I have tried to define `const strings` as objects with callback property but it didn't work. Also I was experimenting with async await combinations but it didn't work either. I have probably insufficient knowledge of Vue components rendering.

Comment: I think that you should begin with an array of just 1 string and then wait for the `TypeWriter` component to emit an event, e.g. `@ready`. Then the handler of this event will push your next string to the array of strings. Then the new `TypeWriter` will emit its `ready` event - and you will push another string to the array of strings. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've got your goal right.

I came up with an idea to solve it much simpler, not using events, but using a buffer.

Here is the playground with a very basic implementation to demonstrate my idea with buffer.

```js
const { createApp, ref, watch, onMounted } = Vue

const TypeWriter = { 
  props: {
    strings: {
      type: Array,
      default: ['']
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
 
    const buffer = ref('');
    const length = ref(-1);
    
    watch(() => props.strings.length, 
      (newVal) => {
          if (newVal - 1 > length.value) {
            buffer.value = buffer.value + props.strings[newVal-1] + "|";
            length.value = newVal - 1;
          }
    });
        
    const printerOutput = ref('');
    const printerPosition = ref(0);
    const printer = () => {    
      if (buffer.value.length > printerPosition.value) {
        printerOutput.value += 
          (buffer.value[printerPosition.value] == '|') ? '<br/>' : buffer.value[printerPosition.value];
        printerPosition.value++;
      }
      setTimeout(printer, 25);
    }  
    
    onMounted(() => {
      printer();
    })
    
    return { buffer, length, printerOutput, printerPosition, printer }
  },
  template: `<div class="typewriter-message" ref="messageWrapper" v-html="printerOutput"></div>`
}

const App = {
   components: {
     TypeWriter
   },
   setup() {
     const strings = ref([]);   
     const addString = () => {     
        strings.value.push(`This is the message ${strings.value.length + 1}.`);
     }
    return { strings, addString }
   }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.typewriter-message {
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <button @click="addString">Send a new message</button><br/>
  <type-writer :strings="strings"></type-writer>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuepic/vue-datepicker@4.2.0/dist/vue-datepicker.iife.js"></script>
```